# Hello, Trying to solve a complex trig problem

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to understand and solve this problem. If anyone is willing to help out I appreciate you! :)
Problem:
Choose a value of w between 0.01 and 0.05 and again plot the graph of $f(t) = \sin(2\pi t) + \sin(2\pi (1 + w) t)$, but this time also include the graph of the envelope $\sin x + \sin y = 2 \sin ((x + y) / 2) \cos ((x - y) / 2)$ (found using the sum to product formula) and -1 times the envelope, all in the same picture. Include the plot with your solutions.

Comment: By any chance do you play the guitar?  If your guitar is out of tune, and you finger what should be the same note on two different strings, and play them both, you will hear "beats"  And the beats will slow as the difference in frequencies gets to be small.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they want you to do is to graph ...
$$ f(t)=sin(2\pi t)+sin(2 \pi t (1+\omega))  $$

$$g(t)= 2 cos(\pi \omega t) $$

$$h(t)= -2 cos( \pi \omega t) $$

on the same axes, your graph should end up looking like this $(\omega = 0.03)$ ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the help.